# How does active storage mapping works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm facing a ruby on rails application which use active storage as file manager.

Now i want to migrate those files to an azure blob storage.
To do this I need to map database entries from an active storage to our own storage tables.

The folder structure for the active storage looks like this:
[image]

And the related database tables like this:
[image]

[image]

I can't find a way to match the file on the storage with an entry of the database.
Neither the filename or key gives me any idea on how to map those.

Am I missing something? How can I get the related active storage file based on the database entries?

I have tried to find a match between the database file names or key values and the active storage folder structue, without success.

Answer (score 1):

Says we have model

```rb
class MyFirstModel < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :my_attachment
end
```

And we decide to attach some file to first Post

```rb
MyFirstModel.first.my_attachment.attach(io: File.open("/path/to/my_first.file"), filename: "my_first.file")
```

Now let's check it

```rb
blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.last

blob.key
# => "7zs2snslr8ehnhlcz0c7dzz96k98"

blob.filename.to_s
# => "my_first.file"
```

And we can find this file

```rb
active_storage_config = Rails.configuration.active_storage
storage_root_dir = active_storage_config.service_configurations[active_storage_config.service.to_s]["root"]

Dir[File.join(storage_root_dir, "**", "*", blob.key)]
# => ["/path_to_app/storage/7z/s2/7zs2snslr8ehnhlcz0c7dzz96k98"]
```

You can define some method

```rb
def find_filepath_by_blob(blob)
  active_storage_config = Rails.configuration.active_storage
  storage_root_dir = active_storage_config.service_configurations[active_storage_config.service.to_s]["root"]

  Dir[File.join(storage_root_dir, "**", "*", blob.key)].first
end
```

This way we can find all files

```rb
ActiveStorage::Attachment.includes(:blob).find_each do |attachment|
  blob = attachment.blob

  puts <<~INFO
    Attachment ID: #{attachment.id}
    Attachment model: #{attachment.record_type}
    Attachment model ID: #{attachment.record_id}
    Filepath: #{find_filepath_by_blob(blob)}
    Filename: #{blob.filename}

  INFO
end

# will print
#
# Attachment ID: 1
# Attachment model: MyFirstModel
# Attachment model ID: 1
# Filepath: /path_to_app/storage/7z/s2/7zs2snslr8ehnhlcz0c7dzz96k98
# Filename: my_first.file
#
# Attachment ID: 3
# Attachment model: MyOtherModel
# Attachment model ID: 22
# Filepath: /path_to_app/storage/sv/yb/svybg3pr5kme2uxzkiupjqykxrr5
# Filename: some.file
```

Of course you can make what you want instead just printing this info. For example upload to some cloud